# Transition effects between responsive designs

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, responsive-design

I am trying to mimic a specific type of responsive functionality and I'm finding it hard to research specifically what I want.

Basically it is a form of responsive design wherein if the window is resized, there is a slight pause, and then the entire site layout smoothly animates to correctly fit the new window or device size.

You can see an example of what I'm talking about here: http://www.briannathanhartwell.com/

I usually use media queries and work through breakpoints. The only way I can see this working is through some global JavaScript function, that fires on a window resize and then causes a whole bunch of JavaScript animations. Would that be accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that would be easily accomplished by using css3 transition properties like:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

you just need to apply them on your media queries conditions.

please take  a look at this examples:
http://css-tricks.com/animated-media-queries/

**NOTE: IE9 does not support the CSS3 Transitions style.**

Answer (score 1):

Even though I don't see much animations on your example, I would like to to answer your question.

You can set an eventListener, which resizes and realigns the page, depending on the size. Within the eventListener you have certain breakpoints for certain layouts.

A surely more elegant way would be just to manipulate the css depending though media queries and use transitions to change to corresponding values.

```
font-size: 200px;
transition: color 12s, font-size 12s;
```

Here a small example: (not to good to view in fiddle, copy paste it into your local IDE).
http://jsfiddle.net/jcyacdmv/
cheers,